# SQLite: INSERT or REPLACE certain columns, don't overwrite others with NULL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Imagine I have a table (refrigerator) with columns: (date(pk), fruits, veggies, starches, sweets). Here's an example row:

```
date     | fruits | veggies | starches | sweets 
20180220 | melon  | potato  |  pasta   | fudge
```

I want to insert or replace only certain columns in refrigerator with the following:

```
> INSERT or REPLACE into refrigerator (date, fruits, veggies, starches) VALUES ("20180220", "apple", "carrot", "bread")
```

When I do this, if I have not specified a value for (sweets), it is overwritten with NULL.

```
date     | fruits | veggies | starches | sweets 
20180220 | apple  | carrot  |  bread   | NULL
```

What would be the proper way to do this that doesn't replace values that I've specified?

I'm sure this is something blatantly obvious. Feel free to laugh at me.

Comment: Use `UPDATE`? SQL queries are usually very fast, so you could check if the thing exists before deciding to use `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.

Comment: Are you suggesting **INSERT or UPDATE** instead of **INSERT or REPLACE**? I basically want a one liner that adds a new row if the (date) is unique, but replaces only certain values if the (date) is not unique without NULLing a valid value in the (sweets) column.

Comment: @bebocure You won't get that functionality, so simply check if the primary key is in the table already, then perform your insert. The COALESCE function will help you keep existing column values during an UPDATE. However, there is no magic statement that will combine all of this functionality.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA _THIS_ is what I wanted to hear. I guess I was expecting magic. Thank you for all the effort you put into your answer. I'll see if I can fit this into the Python script that I am using and proceed from there.

Comment: I corrected myself with the UNION ALL solution below. I guess it's not so magic after all; it's just that REPLACE can't do it alone, and neither can COALESCE.

Comment: What's really funny to me is that the first time in weeks I come to SE to see if there are any questions I can answer or comment on (this one), and the next day I run into this _exact situation_ on the mobile app I'm working on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now it works as intended, and will also INSERT the row if it does not exist.
It won't function properly without the UNION ALL. The first SELECT uses COALESCE() to preserve existing column values in the case where a row does exist. The second SELECT with NOT EXISTS covers the case where the row does not exist, so it constructs one.  Therefore, the UNION ALL only ever returns 1 row: the "merged" row from an existing row, or a brand new one. Then, REPLACE INTO replaces this merged/created row back into the table by primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE refrigerator
  (
  date TEXT(8) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , fruits TEXT(50) NULL
  , veggies TEXT(50) NULL
  , starches TEXT(50) NULL
  , sweets TEXT(50) NULL
  );

INSERT INTO refrigerator (date, fruits, veggies, starches, sweets)
VALUES ("20180220", "melon", "potato", "pasta", "fudge");

REPLACE INTO refrigerator (date, fruits, veggies, starches, sweets)
SELECT
  date
  , COALESCE("apple", fruits) as fruits
  , COALESCE("carrot", veggies) as veggies
  , COALESCE("bread", starches) as starches
  , COALESCE(NULL, sweets) as sweets
 FROM
   refrigerator
 WHERE
   date = "20180220"
UNION ALL
SELECT
  T.date, T.fruits, T.veggies, T.starches, T.sweets
FROM
(
SELECT
  "20180220" as date
  , "apple" as fruits
  , "carrot" as veggies
  , "bread" as starches
  , NULL as sweets
) AS T
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM refrigerator AS R WHERE R.date = T.date);

SELECT date, fruits, veggies, starches, sweets FROM refrigerator;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle: [Refrigerator SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/22e78/42)

[image: Results]

Comment: I don't have enough rep to upvote you, but I'm marking you as the answer unless someone else knows another way to handle this. Thank you very much for your time and effort. You're the man.

Comment: Thanks! I just did you even better with REPLACE INTO.

Comment: @bebocure keep in mind that if you don't have an existing row with the same `date` value - you will have to "insert" it into the database everytime.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA just change the `SELECT date` to `SELECT "20180220"` and you got my vote there too :)

Comment: @PittsburghDBA check out my solution - did I over-complicate my question?

Answer (score 8):

I solved this issue using two lines.

```
UPDATE refrigerator SET fruits='apple', veggies='carrot', starches='bread' WHERE date='20180220';
```

then

```
INSERT or IGNORE INTO refrigerator (fruits, veggies, starches) VALUES ("apple", "carrot", "bread");
```

I was thinking of things backwards, which might have over-complicated the answers here. I first UPDATE specific columns if a row with the (date) exists. The next line will insert a new row with needed info if it doesn't exist - ignores it if it does.

Are there any complications that may arise with this way of doing it? I've tested it and it all works as expected so far.

Comment: That is more straightforward. The original requirement was to one-shot it, so that's what you got.

Comment: You still technically answered correctly. Answer is yours. I found a way to make this a two-liner in my script, rather than having to keep it as a one-liner. Thanks again @PittsburghDBA.

Comment: Nice collaborating with you!

Answer (score 1):

At the time the question was asked, this feature wasn't available in SQLite.

I solved this problem using an UPSERT (https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html).

```
INSERT INTO refrigerator (date, fruits, veggies, starches) VALUES ("20180220", "apple", "carrot", "bread")
 ON CONFLICT(date) DO UPDATE SET fruits="apple", veggies="carrot", starches="bread";
```

This tries to INSERT data into the database, when there is a conflict due to a uniqueness constraint, it does an UPDATE; therefore the existing data is left intact, only the specified columns are changed.

Answer (score 0):

To update existing data use the Update

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_update_query.htm

example to update the fruits column to apple use

Update refigerator set fruits = 'Apple' where YOURWHERECLAUSEHERE

As for inserting what are expecting to be inserted if you don't provide anything? The program is not going to read your mind.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter - to clarify, it'd be best to simply iterate through each column with UPDATE? I was really hoping for a way to INSERT if a new (date) but REPLACE/UPDATE if the (date) is a duplicate and only change the values listed without NULLing out the sweets column with a single command.

Comment: @bebocure Your question was fine as is. "I want to insert or replace *only certain columns*..."

Comment: I was definitely misunderstanding the question. Sorry.

Comment: Me, too! I glossed over the "INSERT" piece and got hung up on "certain columns".

Comment: @JoelLibby my solution was essentially your solution. Just wanted to thank you. If I had 15 rep, I'd give you a real upvote. :)